# "Toroidal transformer action in the presence of total B field confinement" (?!) Is Wikipedia wrong?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-field, toroid

Wikipedia has [an article about toroidal transformers and inductors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toroidal_inductors_and_transformers). It is well known that an ideal toroidally wound coil has total magnetic field confinement due to symmetry **in the case where the current through the coil is constant**. That is, the magnetic field is confined within the toroid, and (with an ideally wound coil) is zero outside the toroid. However, the authors of the Wikipedia article seem to have misunderstood this to mean that there could be (with an ideal winding) total magnetic field confinement in a toroidally wound coil **with time varying current**.

The article (as of Jan. 2024) has a subsection entitled "Total B field confinement by toroidal inductors" which begins with the correct statement

> **In some circumstances**, the current in the winding of a toroidal inductor contributes only to the B field inside the windings. It does not contribute to the magnetic B field outside the windings. **This is a consequence of symmetry and Ampère's circuital law.**[Emphasis added!]

It then goes on to describe "Sufficient conditions for total internal confinement of the B field". Unfortunately, it fails to note that a *necessary* condition, and therefore an essential part of any set of sufficient conditions, for total internal confinement of the B field is that the induced electric field must be time invariant. Ampère's circuital law, is not an unqualified law of classical electrodynamics, but is a special case of Ampère's circuital law *with Maxwell's addition*. Ampère's circuital law, by itself states that

$$\nabla \times \vec{B} = \mu_0 \vec{J}$$

(where \$\vec{J}\$ is the current density (due to the movement of charges).

Maxwell's addition changes Ampère's original law to

$$\nabla \times \vec{B} = \mu_0 \vec{J} + \mu_0\epsilon_0\frac{d\vec{E}}{dt}$$

Since the \$\vec{E}\$ field extends *outside* of the toroid, the term \$\mu_0\epsilon_0\frac{d\vec{E}}{dt}\$ will be non-zero *outside* of the toroid if the derivative of the \$\vec{E}\$ field is non-zero.

The claim that there is no magnetic field outside of the toroid implies that every Poynting vector outside of the toroid would be zero. But this provokes the question of how a toroidal transformer, with the secondary in the "hole" of the toroid could possibly work.  The article confronts this by claiming the current in the secondary creates the magnetic field outside the toroid (i.e. in the hole).

This image from Wikipedia illustrates this argument.

[image]

However, I am quite convinced that there is a magnetic field in space around a sinusoidally energized toroidal *inductor*, including the hole, (with no transformer secondary), based upon my understanding of Ampère's Circuital Law with Maxwell's addition.

Is my understanding correct? Or is there an error in my understanding?

Comment: Afraid I don't have a feel for this (it's been a long time since I did fields, and I don't recall if I worked with that exact term at all, heh), but another important factor is the wave propagation around a real, permeable-loaded toroid, particularly at switching harmonics if that should be relevant to a given application. It would be interesting to know if the low-frequency tail of this nonuniformity is comparable to the term in question.

Answer (score 1):

What they are presenting in that analysis is the quasi-static solution, as they state:

[image]

where they ignore the term you are concerned about:

[image]

This is only valid for low frequencies, the actual limit is geometry dependent.

Comment: Perhaps this was not a good question for this site. I am tempted to respond to your answer at length by editing my question, but I am reluctant to make such edits since you have already provided an answer, and I don't want to be unfair. It seems that the reasonable place for me to reply to your answer in depth would be in a chat room. Are you open to such a chat?  https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/150632/total-magnetic-field-confinement-in-ac-driven-toroidal-inductor-transformer

Comment: I don't think there is much more to add. You have discovered the poynting vector that moves energy in/out of the electric field each cycle and which pales into insignificance for any practical transformer when compared to the poynting vector that appears when secondary current flows.  Of course we are assuming that the whole apparatus is small compared to the wavelength.

Comment: 1/2 The field that creates emf in the secondary may "pale into insigificance" **compared to** the poyting vector that appears when secondary current flows. But without that "insignificant" field, there would be no emf to drive the secondary current in the first place. Further, these two field components are out of phase if I am not mistaken. Saying there is no field external to the toroid is like saying there is no magnetization current in a transformer, because it "pales into insignificance." compared to the secondary current and induced primary current.

Comment: 2/2 But what is insignificant depends upon the use one wishes to make of a given parameter. In understanding the behavior of a toroidal transformer, I believe the, typically ignored, field external to the toroid plays an essential role. (Further, I believe the Wikipedia image to be wrong. The Poynting vector for transfer of power from the torroidal winding to the center conductor _curves_ and then runs parallel to the central secondary wire (in both directions) as that is how power is transferred along wires. When a P. vector goes _into_ a wire (and not out again) it creates heat, not emf/amps

Comment: The electric field that creates the EMF and causes the current flow in the secondary is significant, as is the magnetic field that results from secondary current flow - these create the significant poynting vector that represents power flow to the secondary. There is a much smaller magnetic field created by the time changing electric field that combines with the electric field to give a much smaller poynting vector representing the flow of energy in/out of the electric field. The Wikipedia diagram could be improved, showing the secondary as a loop with the poynting vector along its length.